# passing functions into angular instead of 'function()'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working with angular a lot lately and one thing I wanted to do was use a declared function instead of a place that takes the word "function() {}", like in a promise callback for example. I had a few server requests that, on error, all do the same thing, so instead of saying:

```
.then(function(data) {

}, function(error) {

});
```

I wanted to do the following:

```
.then(function(data) {
}, handleError(error));

function handleError(error) { console.log(error); }
```

but it wasnt working. Did I make a mistake in how I tried to do this or is this just not possible?

Comment: `}, handleError.bind(null, error));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing `handleError(error)`, you're *calling* the function (with some `error` variable as the argument, which probably doesn't even exist). You just want to *pass* the function:

```
.then(function(data) {
     …
}, handleError);
```

[No parenthesis!](https://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2)